# Convergence in probability of maximum

Tags: probability

Assume that $X_1,X_2,\ldots \overset{iid}{\sim} P$ and $X_i \geq 0$ and define $M_n = \max_{i=1}^{n} X_i$. I'm trying to show that $M_n/n \overset{p}{\to} 0$ iff $nP(X_1 > n) \overset{n}{\to} 0$.

There is a useful inequality that $P(M_n > x) \leq nP(X_1 > x)$ but I can't see how to leverage this to solve this problem. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For a given $\epsilon > 0$, note that $$1 - \mathbb{P}(M_n/n > \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(M_n \leq \epsilon n) = \prod\limits_{j = 1}^n\mathbb{P}(X_j \leq n\epsilon) = (\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq n\epsilon))^n = (1 - \mathbb{P}(X_1 > n\epsilon))^n.$$

The left-hand-side goes to $1$ for every $\epsilon$ precisely when $M_n/n \to 0$ in probability.  As for the right-hand-side, try to see that $n\mathbb{P}(X_1 > n) \to 0$ implies $n\mathbb{P}(X_1 > \epsilon n) \to 0$ for any given $\epsilon$.  Expand the right-hand-side using binomial theorem, and see that convergence occurs if and only if $n\mathbb{P}(X_1 > \epsilon n) \to 0$, completing the proof.

Comment: Not sure I see the "only if" part. If I expand the RHS I get something like
$(1-P(X_1>n\epsilon))^n\approx1-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k(nP(X>n\epsilon))^k$?

Comment: @Gaunne You don't even need to expand the RHS. Just use $(1-\frac {\alpha_n} n)^n\to 1$ iff $\alpha_n\to 0$.

Comment: @A.S. I really like this fact you mentioned. I agree with that intuition. Any reasonably short justification/intuition on why its true?

Comment: @Gau Intuition: $(1+\frac \alpha n)^n\to e^\alpha$ for fixed $\alpha$.